# Is it possible to register a public server, and protect the orgin of the actual processing server?

Tags: security, web, p2p, distributed-computing

Tough question. It has to do mainly with security, but also computers. Probably not been done yet.

I was wondering, is it possible to host for example a web application, yet be **able to hide** **where** the **actual server is**, and, or who is the **originator**, making it **very very** hard ( practically impossible ) for some one to **track the origin** of the server, and who is behind it?

I was thinking that this might be possible through a **third party server**, preferably with an owner unrelated to the **proxy** sites. But the question then also becomes an issue of **reliability** **of** the **third party**.

Does the **TOR network** have support for **registering for recieving** incoming requests rather than outgoing ones? How secure would that be? Might it be possible that the TOR network has been infiltrated by for example a big goverment ( read USA ) ( dont get angry, please enlighten me as I do not know much of how the TOR network is hosted ).

How can one possibly create such a secure third party server, that preferably does not even know who the final recipient of the request is? Third party companies might be **subjected** **to** **pressure** from **goverments**, either directly from **powerful** **nations** such as USA, or by the **USA applying pressure** on the goverments of the country where the server is, applying pressure on the company behind it, and **force you** to enable a **backdoor**. ( Just my wild fantasy, think worst case scenario is my motto :) ).

I just came with the idea, that being that this is **probably** **impossible**, the best way would be to have a bunch of **distributed servers**, across **several nations**, make it as **hard as possible** to go through each and one of them to find the next bouncing server. This would have to be in a linked list, with one public server being registered on a DNS. If compromised, the public server needs to be replaced with another one.

request from **user0** -> **server1** -> **server2** -> **server3** -> **final processing server** -> response to **user0** or through the incoming server chain.

When sending a **response to someone**, could it be done **using UDP** rather than TCP and hide who the sender was ( also in a web application ) ? So that a middle man **listening on user0 computer** incoming responses ( and outgoing requests ) do not **figure** **out who the final** processing server is, if we decide to **respond directly** to user0 from the final processing server?

The IP of **server1 will be public and known to anyone**, server1 will send the message to server2 and it is possibly to figure out by listening directly behind server1 traffic node, but perhaps it could hide its own origin if not being listened to directly, so that if **big goverments** have **filters** on big **traffic nodes or routers**, they **wouldn't be able** to track **who it came from**, and therefore what the message to server2 is intended for. It would **blend in** with all **other requests**.

Anyhow, if you have followed my thoughts this far I think you should know by now what I am thinking about.

Could this be possibly through a **P2P network**, with a **central server behind it**, and have the **P2P network deliver it to the final server** respond in some pattern? The idea is to have one processing server, and then have "minor", "cheaper" servers that acts as proxys?

Why I keep saying central server, is that I am thinking web. But any thoughts on the matter is interesting.

For those that wonders, why... I am looking into creating as secure as possible, and that could withstand goverment pressure ( read BlackBerry, Skype and others ). 
This is also a theoretical question.

PS. 
I **would also** be **interested in** knowing how one have a **distributed SECURE database** ( for keeping usernames, friendlists and passwords for example ) but this time, it is not neccessery for it to be on the web. A P2P software with a distributed secure database.

Thanks!

Comment: If you would ask a new question for your PS, I'll add an answer for that - ping me with the link here.

Comment: PS ? I am not sure what you mean :)

Comment: You've asked two different questions in the one question - it's better to separate them, so the various answers don't get confusing. If you would move your second question (about distributed databases) to a new question, I'll answer it :)

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294323/secure-distributed-database

Comment: Not tough, not new at all. Also not really programming-related; should be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're reinventing Tor. You should research Tor more fully before going further. In particular, see [Hidden Service Protocol](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en). Tor is not perfect, but you should understand it before you try to reinvent it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an ant's nest, follow the ants. If you want to find the original server, follow the ip packets. If you meet a proxy server not willing to provide their path, call the server administrator and have your men in black put a gun on his head. If he does not comply, eliminate the administrator and the server. Carry on following the ants in their new path. Repeat the operation until server is reached or server can't communicate anymore.

So no, you can't protect the origin and keep your server up and running when your men in black can reach any physical entity.